# IgnoreIfAlreadyExists is set to True but updates happen

Tags: module

We have a VS project module with 'IgnoreIfAlreadyExists' set to true.

What this means is that: if a similar file exists then it will ignore this VS file. However, whenever we make change to the file in module (masterpage), we can see that the master page does get updated.

Why do changes happen when IgnoreIfAlreadyExists is set to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got it mixed up!

If set to true it will provision even if the file already exists!

> Optional Boolean. TRUE to provision the view even if the file aready
>   exists at the specified URL; otherwise, FALSE
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459213.aspx

Comment: Is it good practice to set this to true..?

Comment: @variable Yes. When set to `true` you don't have to manually upload, check-in and publish the new files. I have never been in a situation where setting it to `false` was desired.

Answer (score 13):

Things is a little more complex than the other answers suggest:

**IgnoreIfAlreadyExists**
Only controls whether activating the feature should fail if the file already exists.

Usually you want to set it to true as that'll allow you to activate/deactivate the feature without problems. But be aware that it'll NEVER update the file content nor properties by itself.

Usually you'll set this to true, so you're able to reactivate the feature. But this comes with the risk of your feature thinking that it got it's file deployed when what really exist is a user file with that url. So you might want to use the value false if your feature cleans up after itself when being deactivated and you want to stop activating the feature if the file already exists.

The attribute is ignored if `ReplaceContent` is set to true.

**ReplaceContent**
Controls whether activating the feature should revert a customized (Unghosted) file to being uncustomized (Ghosted) AND set properties as specified. May fail if checked out by other user.

**Ghosting of files**
The attributes above are only in effect when the feature is being (re)activated which probably isn't what's happening to you.

What's happening to you is that when you deploy files to SharePoint using File element in Module elements what SharePoint creates in the Content Database is just a record telling that the file exists in this Document Library but with a pointer into the location in SharePointRoot where the file content is read from. This is called that the file is Uncustomized (Ghosted).

If someone goes and modifies the file using SharePoint UI (or object model) the modified content will be stored in the Content Database and read from here. This is called that the file is Customized (Unghosted).

If the file stays Uncustomized (Ghosted) as most files do, then the mere act of deploying (updating) a WSP with new content will change the file in SharePointRoot and thereby update what is read (used) without the feature being reactivated and this will happen regardless of the value of the above attributes.

Comment: @Per Thanks for the answer. Clarified a lot of doubts. But the files which I have attached to a module are getting deleted and reuploaded on deploying. Is there a way to stop that? I tried setting both IgnoreIfAlreadyExists which throws an error on "False" and ReplaceContent="False" but it still deletes all the files and reuploads them.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Roberts's answer, if you are using SP2013 there is one more attribute `ReplaceContent`. You might want to use it. From MSDN

> Optional Boolean. TRUE to overwrite the previously installed version of the file with a new version when the element manifest is being applied as part of an upgrade of the parent Feature; otherwise FALSE.

For the difference between the two check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/overwriting-ghostable-files-in-sharepoint-2013-libraries-using-feature-elements.aspx)

Comment: IgnoreIfAlreadyExists also does the replace anyways right? just asking.

Comment: Correct, this ReplaceContent switch is a bit more powerful in some scenarios :)

Comment: No IgnoreIfAlreadyExists does not replace. Please see the link I have attached in the answer above.

Comment: I never said it would replace, I said it would successfully activate

Comment: oh sorry the above comment was for @variable not you. My bad :-)

Comment: Suppose we have deployed a wsp to our clients containing an sample.txt file with content "test". Then, when the contents of this file change to say "test123" we publish the new wsp with ignoreifalreadyexists=true and give to clients. You are saying that this actually doesnot update the test to test123 in the file?

Comment: Depends on if it is Ghosted or not.. @variable

Comment: If ghosted = yes?

Comment: @variable: If ghosted then yes.