# Why does my custom pagelayout not overwrite the old version?

Tags: module

I have created a custom page layout. It is deployed for the first time. I did modified and deployed it again. Why does the pagelayout is still showing me the old one? On the 15 hives folder I can see the new one.

This is de module in my solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="masterpage" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="masterpage\">
    <File Url="NewsArticle.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE" Level="Published">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Nieuwspagina" />
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="Nieuws Pagina Layout voor Brabant Water" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/NewsPagePreview.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/NewsPagePreview.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#Nieuws;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003ce876821eac4ec8aad81ac501ebcd07;#"/>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

I already add this in de module and it is still not working:

```
ReplaceContent="TRUE" Level="Published"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have changed something on that Pagelayout through the UI or through SharePoint Designer, then the Pagelayout has been Unghosted, which means the file will not be updated through deployment.

However a mere reactivation of the feature installing this should be sufficient.

You can read [Per Jakobsens answer on how this works here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/95103/2536)